# Change the initial scene in spritekit swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skscene

how to change initial scene in new xcode3? I found lots of instructions, but all of it working with this code:

```
extension SKNode {
  class func unarchiveFromFile(file : String) -> SKNode? {
    if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file, ofType: "sks") {
        var sceneData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)!
        var archiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: sceneData)

        archiver.setClass(self.classForKeyedUnarchiver(), forClassName: "SKScene")
        let scene = archiver.decodeObjectForKey(NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey) as! MenuScene
        archiver.finishDecoding()
        return scene
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

}

But new Xcode project, GameViewController not contain this part of code and when I try to copy, it not work. So I make MainScene.swift and MainScene.sks and want to set these scene to main. What next?

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using an .sks file for your scene layouts use the following code.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {

        // Load the SKScene from 'MainScene.sks'
        if let mainScene = MainScene(fileNamed: "MainScene")  {

            // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
            mainScene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
            // Present the scene
            view.presentScene(mainScene)
        }

        view.showsFPS = true
        view.showsDrawCount = true
        view.showsNodeCount = true
        view.showsPhysics = true
        view.showsDrawCount = true
    }
}
```